# Oracle SQL: Multiple Subqueries Unioned Without Running Original Query Multiple Times

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, union, subquery

So I've got a very large database, and need to work on a subset ~1% of the data to dump into an excel spreadsheet to make a graph.  Ideally, I could select out the subset of data and then run multiple select queries on that, which are then UNION'ed together.  Is this even possible?  I can't seem to find anyone else trying to do this and would improve the performance of my current query quite a bit.  Right now I have something like this:

```
SELECT (
     SELECT (
          SELECT(
                long list of requirements
          )
          UNION
          SELECT(
                slightly different long list of requirements
          )
     )
)
```

and it would be nice if i could group the commonalities of the two long requirements and have simple differences between the two select statements being unioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Oracle 9i or later, you can make use of subquery factoring (AKA Common Table Expression (CTE) in SQL Server).  It uses the WITH syntax:

```
WITH inline_view_name AS (
   SELECT *
     FROM YOUR_TABLEs)
SELECT 
  FROM inline_view_name a
 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  FROM inline_view_name b
 WHERE ...
```

...and can be reused like you see in the example.